# SNMP MIB file resource

Tags: switch, snmp, mib

My company(ISP) has 50+ switch models in our network, we manage them via SNMP from our web based intranet, for some Huawei switches we can't figure out the OID's we need (we usualy figure the OID we need our self, beacause we usualy don't receive MIB files from the hardware vendor).

Is there any online archive/resource where we can find MIB files ?

P.S. For example I can't find the OID to save configuration for Huawei S23xx series.

**Thank you**

Comment: By the way I have found the OID's for Huawei Save .1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.6.10.1.2.4.1.2.1 i 1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.6.10.1.2.4.1.9.1 i 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are publicly available databases like [OIDView's MIB database](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/detail.html) but why don't you simply ask the manufacturer?

Comment: Thank you, we already asked those in charge of supply, but I don't know why they didn't get us anything [maibe they are to lasy to ask the manufacturer, who knows ...]. Do you know if MIB's are copyright protected ?

Comment: I am not a lawyer, so I have no idea about copyright issues. Usually, you can ask the manufacturer's tech support to get the SNMP MIBs and the OID information you need without any major problems. I would especially expect this to work well with a manufacturer who focuses on enterprise and carrier gear.